# Swift Editor Placeholder in source file

Tags: ios, swift, placeholder

hi have problem with the swift error "Swift Editor Placeholder In Source File"
This is my code

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: <#T##IndexPath#>) as! CustomBrandCell

    let brandImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: self.brands[indexPath.row].name)!

    cell.brandImageView.image = brandImage

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Have you searched on SO?

Comment: Have a look here for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37352738/swift-editor-placeholder-in-source-file. In your case the problem is in this line `let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: <#T##IndexPath#>) as! CustomBrandCell`. Notice the <#T##IndexPath#>, that is a placeholder which you must replace with some "real" code...in your case a parameter of type `indexPath`

Comment: The error is *very* straightforward and there's an obvious placeholder in the second line. I've voted to close this question as "a simple typographical error".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the same question many times on SO. But none of them gave the answer I was looking for.

You get the `Placeholder in source file` when you have one of these (where it says "String" with a blue background) in your code.

[image]

A placeholder is for us programmers. It says "here should be a value of the type String". You can click on it and start typing, to simply replace it with for example a variable name. You can also press tab to automatically select the next placeholder. This is very useful when you are calling a function with multiple parameters (and therefore multiple placeholders).

A placeholder is actually just normal text (<#T##Strign#>), but XCode "translates" it to look like how it does.

In your case the error is on line three.

```
...withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: <#T##IndexPath#>) as! CustomBrandCell
```

As you can see `<#T##IndexPath#>` is a placeholder as normal text as I mentioned earlier. You probably want this to be `indexPath`

Answer (score 5):

Try cmd + shift + k to clean the project and run your code again. This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. hope solve your problem

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{

      // get a reference to your storyboard cell
     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CustomBrandCell

     let brandImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: self.brands[indexPath.row].name)!

     cell.brandImageView.image = brandImage

     return cell
}
```