# Getting "Editor Placeholder in Source File" in xCode project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a project which was in Swift 2 that I just converted to Swift 3 (using xCode 8.3) and I am getting this error.

"Editor Placeholder in Source File" . for this line of code. Any thoughts? I am not an experienced developer so simplicity is appreciated :).

```
var _alertBuilder: JSSAlertView = JSSAlertView(coder: NSCoder)
```

Comment: The line `coder: NSCoder` is the culprit here. You have to pass a `NSCoder` to solve this issue, currently there is a placeholder sitting right there and `coder` is not getting any `NSCoder` and that is why it is throwing this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift Editor Placeholder in source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41222786/swift-editor-placeholder-in-source-file)

Comment: Hi, I'm pretty green here. Can someone suggest some syntax to solve this issue?  The variable is being called later like this  [code] func didResolveAddress(_ address: String) {
        if _confirmFramerConnect {
            if !_alertBuilder.isAlertOpen { [ [code]